# Cannot pass data to EditText from Mysql

Tags: android, mysql

i have activity that can't show data from Mysql to Edittext.

When i choose a single data it just error on my project

in my logcat,i can receive single data,but not pass into my Edittext.

here is my source:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createperson);

         firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcreatefirstname);
         middlename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmiddlename);
         lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editlastname);
         alias = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editaliasname);
         gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editgender);
         city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcity);
         date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editdate);
         month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmonth);
         year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edityear);

        noID = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

            new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...param) {

            try {
                List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID_Person", noID));
                String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/getDetails.php?ID_Person="+noID;
                 JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                         url_product_detials, "GET", params);
                 Log.d("Single Person Details", json.toString());
                 JSONArray productObj = json
                         .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
                 for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {

                     JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(i);


                     String first = person.getString("First_Name_Person");
                     String middle = person.getString("Middle_Name_Person");
                     String last = person.getString("Last_Name_Person");
                     String al = person.getString("Alias_Person");
                     String gen = person.getString("Gender_Person");
                     String cty = person.getString("City_Birth_Person");
                     String dte = person.getString("Date_Birth_Person");
                     String mth = person.getString("Month_Birth_Person");
                     String yr = person.getString("Year_Birth_Person");

                     firstname.setText(first);
                     middlename.setText(middle);
                     lastname.setText(last);
                     alias.setText(al);
                     gender.setText(gen);
                     city.setText(cty);
                     date.setText(dte);
                     month.setText(mth);
                     year.setText(yr);


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my logcat error

```
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4075)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10329)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4524)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4467)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7325)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8907)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3684)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.sd.tri.SingleView$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(SingleView.java:114)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.sd.tri.SingleView$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(SingleView.java:1)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-23 02:28:51.929: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     ... 4 more
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362): Activity com.sd.tri.SingleView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d5f0b8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-320,96} that was originally added here
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sd.tri.SingleView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d5f0b8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-320,96} that was originally added here
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at com.sd.tri.SingleView$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(SingleView.java:75)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at com.sd.tri.SingleView.onCreate(SingleView.java:64)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-23 02:28:55.769: E/WindowManager(1362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please somebody help me..

Comment: You are updating the UI from the background thread (`doInBackground` method). You should do this in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: @juraganerka Hi have you solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

In your `AsyncTask` class you perform the network activity in `doInBackground` but when you need to update the user interface, that should be done in `onPostExecute` method.

```
 class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String...param) {
          JSONArray productObj = new JSONArray();
            try {
                List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID_Person", noID));
                String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/getDetails.php?ID_Person="+noID;
                 JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                         url_product_detials, "GET", params);
                 Log.d("Single Person Details", json.toString());
                 productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return productObj;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray productObj) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {

                     JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(i);


                     String first = person.getString("First_Name_Person");
                     String middle = person.getString("Middle_Name_Person");
                     String last = person.getString("Last_Name_Person");
                     String al = person.getString("Alias_Person");
                     String gen = person.getString("Gender_Person");
                     String cty = person.getString("City_Birth_Person");
                     String dte = person.getString("Date_Birth_Person");
                     String mth = person.getString("Month_Birth_Person");
                     String yr = person.getString("Year_Birth_Person");

                     firstname.setText(first);
                     middlename.setText(middle);
                     lastname.setText(last);
                     alias.setText(al);
                     gender.setText(gen);
                     city.setText(cty);
                     date.setText(dte);
                     month.setText(mth);
                     year.setText(yr);


                }

                }
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can see the log as below:
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

it means you change you UI view in another thread ,this is not allowed.